# Difference in Jensen's inequality yields 0?

Tags: probability, inequality, random-variables

I think there is something wrong with the following reasoning, but I don't know where.

**Assumptions:**

- Working in $\mathbb{R}_+$
- $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 3}$
- $C \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 2}$
- $\varphi$ is a concave increasing function with bounded derivative ($\varphi'(x) \leq C$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}_+$)
- $X$ is a positive bounded random variable, with bounded mean and bounded variance.

---

First of all, as $\varphi$ is a concave increasing function, it satisfies the following property for every $x, y \in \mathbb{R}_+$
$$\varphi(y) \le \varphi(x) + \varphi'(x)(y-x).$$
Moreover, by Jensen's inequality, as $\varphi$ is concave, we have 
$$\mathbb{E}[\varphi(X)] \le \varphi(\mathbb{E}[X]) \implies \varphi(\mathbb{E}[X]) - \mathbb{E}[\varphi(X)] \geq 0. \tag{1}$$
But we also have
$$
\begin{align*}
\varphi(\mathbb{E}[X]) - \mathbb{E}[\varphi(X)] &= \mathbb{E}[\varphi(\mathbb{E}[X]) - \varphi(X)]\\
&\leq \mathbb{E}[\varphi'(X)(\mathbb{E}[X]-X)]\\
&\leq C \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X]-X]\\
&= C(\mathbb{E}[X]-\mathbb{E}[X])\\
&= 0\\
\implies\varphi(\mathbb{E}[X]) - \mathbb{E}[\varphi(X)] &\leq 0. \tag{2}
\end{align*}
$$
Equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ together yield
$$\varphi(\mathbb{E}[X]) - \mathbb{E}[\varphi(X)] = 0. \tag{3}$$

---

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't (necessarily) have

$$\varphi'(X)\bigl(\mathbb{E}[X] - X\bigr) \leqslant C\bigl(\mathbb{E}[X] - X\bigr),$$

since $\mathbb{E}[X] - X$ can be negative (and except in trivial cases, it is negative on a set of positive measure). Thus the step

$$\mathbb{E}[\varphi'(X)(\mathbb{E}[X] - X)] \leqslant C\,\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X] - X]$$

is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

$E[\phi'(X)(E[X]-X)] \leq CE[E[X]-X]$ does not follow because $E[X]-X$ may be negative.